# Hide Downloadlink ASP

Tags: asp-classic, download

i'am trying to hide the Downloadlink from some files. They're on a FTP. When i download a file then i can backtrack to the server and crawl some more files but i want to prevent that. I've already searched some solutions but i never got them working.

I have a seperate download.ashx File with th following code. I't a example for only the file download.zip

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed"  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.zip")
Response.WriteFile(ftp://server.de/files/scripts/files/)
Response.End()
```

This is the Hyperlink for the download

```
<a href="download.ashx?download.zip" target=""_blank"">Click here to Download File</a>
```

Everytime when I click the downloadlink i get a Runtime Error:

```
Server Error in '/files/scripts/files' Application.
```

I hope you've some ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer [ASP.NET Create zip file for download: the compressed zipped folder is invalid or corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456842/asp-net-create-zip-file-for-download-the-compressed-zipped-folder-is-invalid-or)

If you can get the download code working you can hide the file location by generating (for example) an asp button that points to the download, rather than a link to the FTP.